# Are questions discussing revenue acceptable here?

Tags: discussion

[Example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4609/webmasters-how-much-money-you-earn-via-your-own-websites). This should be CW at the very least. But do we want discussions of revenue? Is it a real question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions which differ *for every answerer* probably don't belong here - that's a forum thing.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Wanted to be sure before I invoked my new superpowers. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that questions pertaining to business models, including revenue (non-specifically) are appropriate.

For example, discussions comparing:

- AdSense versus other ad networks
- Affiliate versus advertising
- Micropayments